# basic linux x86 assembly minimum number returns incorrectly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, minimum

I wrote this basic **linux x86** assembly app. I expect it to return **3** when I do `echo $?` however the status is always **0**. What am I doing wrong?

```
.section .data
   data_items:
      .long 3,67,34,222,45,2,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0

.section .text
   .global _start

   _start:
      movl $0, %edi
      movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
      movl %eax, %ebx

   start_loop:
      cmpl $0, %eax
      je loop_exit
      incl %edi
      movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
      cmpl %ebx, %eax
      jge start_loop
      movl %eax, %ebx
      jmp start_loop

   loop_exit:
      movl $1, %eax
      int $0x80
```

Note: `%ebx` always contains the status code, and it **should** contain the min value by exit time.

## Fixed:

```
   _start:
      movl $0, %edi
      movl data_items(,%edi,4), %ebx

   start_loop:
      incl %edi
      movl data_items(, %edi, 4), %eax
      cmpl $0, %eax
      je loop_exit

      cmpl %ebx, %eax
      jge start_loop

      movl %eax, %ebx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the terminating zero also participates in the minimum calculation. You check for that zero only after you have already done the check for the minimum. Learn to use a debugger to step through your code.

Consider what happens when you arrive at the last item, the `66`. Follow the code from the `start_loop`. Obviously `66` is not `0` so it continues, increments the index and fetches the next number which is the zero. This is of course less than the minimum so far, thus it's stored into `ebx` and we end up at `start_loop` again, which correctly detects the terminating condition. However `ebx` is already zeroed.

Comment: You are right of course! I hope the book I am reading covers debugging soon.